# Strange behavior with S3 class

Tags: r

I re-wrote the post with reproducible example.

Running the following code will create two objects: *eem* and *eem2*. Additionally, the class eem has a names.eem function used to retrieve the value of the *sample* field.

```
names.eem <- function(x, ...){
  x$sample
}

# First constructor
eem1 <- function(sample){
  eem <- list(sample = sample)
  class(eem) <- "eem"
  return(eem)
}

# Second constructor
eem2 <- function(sample){
  eem <- list(sample = sample)
  class(eem) <- "eem2"
  return(eem)
}

test1 <- eem1("justaname")
test2 <- eem2("justaname")
```

Lets create two different objects:

```
test1 <- eem1("justaname")
test2 <- eem2("justaname")
```

This is "bugged":

```
> str(test1)
List of 1
 $ justaname: chr "justaname"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "eem"
```

This is ok:

```
> str(test2)
List of 1
 $ sample: chr "justaname"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "eem2"
```

The only thing that differs between the 2 objects is that one has a an S3 function (names.eem) associated to it.

This is my SessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2
```

Comment: It seems I cannot recreate this, at least with the information you show in your question.

Comment: @Pascal He is getting spooked by the `- attr(*, "class")` info at the end, the list contents remain the same.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I think OP speaks about the **names**, which become `NA`.

Comment: What does `names(eem)` show _after_ assigning the class to be `"eem"` ?  Maybe the problem is in the `str()` function itself.

Comment: If I create a list `eem` this way: `x <- rnorm(186*147); x <- matrix(x, 186, 147); ex <- seq(from = 220, by = 5, length.out = 47); em <- seq(from = 230, by = 2, length.out = 186); eem <- list(sample="sample1", x=x, ex=ex, em=em)`, I keep the names even after `class(eem) <- "eem"`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oriented me with to a possible problem with my name "setter". I updated the question.

Comment: Maybe you can investigate this and then answer your own question.  I could not reproduce what you saw .

Comment: I still cannot reproduce, with `names<-.eem` in my environment.

Comment: `eem` is both a function and a list??

Comment: Can you start a new session, confirm the bug, and add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your post?

Comment: Also, clarify, with an example if possible, why you think names() is called.

Comment: I just provided a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug, but rather a confusion caused by the shared namespaces in R and is caused by the "eem" class you set up.

When you say:

```
eem1 <- function(sample){
    eem <- list(sample = sample)
    class(eem) <- "eem"
    return(eem)
```

}

```
test1 <- eem1("justname")
```

The following happens inside the function:
eem first becomes a list with one element called sample with value = "justname".
Then when you assign the class "eem" to the eem. It will change the elements name to the `x$sample` which inside the function is `eem$sample = "justname"`.

So, I would not flag this as a bug. You just have to be careful how you name your variables within the same environment.

Also, I would recommend not calling your input variable "sample" as that's already a valid function in base R.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ty @niczky12. As I understand, the simplest way to avoid that would be to not try to override names and maybe choose a better function name?

Comment: @Phillippe Yes, try to avoid using default names. It's never a good idea to use the same names in any programming language.